# Shape detection for set of points in openCV(without using image)?

Tags: c++, iphone, opencv

Given a set of points, is it possible to detect the geometrical shape and/or contour? I could find examples for finding the shape in a image or using a image.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Question is not clear without it.

Comment: Like if I draw a rectangle using finger or stylus in ios device, is it possible to detect shape? by providing set of points to openCV

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Could you please send me the link or the piece of code

Comment: Of what kind of information are your references? E.g. if you want to detect a triangle you can describe it geometrically, but if you want to detect some more special contour/shape, you must have some kind of representation of that contour or class. Is that reference given as an image, or as a set of points, or as something abstract? And you have to describe what it means to "detect" something. Invariance of size/orientation etc desired? Depending on those parameters and others, your question can be answered easily or it might b nrly impossible. Give representative examples or grope in the dark

Comment: The input is set of points like vector of points, the output is a geometrical shape depending upon points(like square,triagle,pentagon,circle).

Comment: If input is image I am able to achieve the solution, I wanted to avoid converting of points to image and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shape detection is a concept and it is independent from the data structure as long as both training and test data has the same structure. So, what is important here is to understand what shape detection is. [Here](https://opencv-code.com/tutorials/detecting-simple-shapes-in-an-image/) you can find a simple shape detection example. This example does not use point sets, but once you understand this example, it would be a piece of cake to implement it.